# Minimizing Waiting Time At Intercom

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, recreational-mathematics

I work in mail delivery and often have to ring at multiple tenants until someone opens the front door.  With modern intercoms, only the last person I have rang up can open the door, the others get blocked.

I asked myself, if for any tenant the probability distribution of the time which passes between me ringing the bell and them trying to open the door is identical (and independent between different tenants), what would be the bell ringing strategy minimizing my expected waiting time?

To put in mathematical terms, let $(X_i)_i$ be an infinite (for reasons of simplicity I assume there is an infinite number of tenants) series of i.i.d. random variables $X_i:\Omega\to(0,\infty)$.  For any strategy $s:{\bf N}\to(0,\infty)$ (which means I wait $s_0$ seconds after ringing at $X_0$, $s_1$ seconds after ringing at $X_1$ if $X_0$ doesn't open, etc.), let the waiting time be denoted by $w_s(\omega)=\sum_{i<k}s_i+X_k(\omega)$ where $k$ is the smallest index with $X_k(\omega)\le s_k$.

The question is then, which $s$ minimizes the expected waiting time $\int_{\omega} w_s(\omega)$?  What would change, if we allow $\infty$ as value for the $X_i$ (i.e. some tenants went out)?  Especially, I'd like to know if an optimal $s$ has to be constant.

Comment: Ever considered changing your job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let us assume that the optimal $s$ has to be a constant (we will treat it as a real value, rather than vector for now). Let us define the probability $p(s)$ to be $$p(s) = \mathbb{P}(X_i \le s).$$ Therefore, the distribution of the smallest index $K(\omega)$ is given by a standard geometric distribution with success parameter $p$. Hence, the expected wait time is 
$$\begin{align} \mathbb{E}(w_s) = \mathbb{E}\left((K-1)s + X_K\right) &= s\left(\mathbb{E}(K-1)\right) + \mathbb{E}X_K \\ &= \frac{s(1-p(s))}{p(s)} + \mathbb{E}(X_i\mid X_i\leq s).\end{align}$$
Therefore, you want to minimize this, w.r.t. $s$ (depending on your distribution of $X_i$ you may be able to get a nice form for such an $s$).

Next, to note that $s$ must be a constant vector, we can formulate this problem as a two-state MDP (states are whether or not we're done waiting), and utilize standard results to state that there must be a stationary, non-randomized optimal policy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Just two notes: First, I don't think there necessarily exists a solution, if my calculations are right, the probability with density $\frac{1}{(t+1)^2}$ would not allow the construction of such an optimal strategy.

Comment: Second, assume there is a distribution such that $s$ is an optimal, constant strategy.  Then, consider the variables $(X'_i)_i$ distributed by $w_s$, i.e. everytime I ring a bell, another delivery guy starts playing the original strategy on a house with the original probability distributions.  In this situation, I could wait the original time $s$ between the rings, but I could also wait $2s$ or $3s$ because it would make no difference if the other guy rings on the next bell or I send a new guy to a new house.

Comment: @fweth What do you mean that the variables are distributed by an expectation? Do you mean that the random variables are constant with value $\mathbb{E}(w_s)$?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I'll fix it!

Comment: Not the expectation, the original waiting time $w_s$ is what I meant.

Comment: The $X_i$ are assumed to have a distribution independent of my choice in strategy? Obviously, if the $X_i$ are strategic they can make my wait time infinite.

Comment: I wrote $X_i$ first but then edited it to $X'_i$, I introduced a new random variable based on the distribution of $w_s$.

Comment: So the idea is really that I have an infinite number of copies of the original house, and at the new house, when I ring the $i$th bell, a delivery guy starts playing the original strategy at the $i$th copy of the original house, the moment he / she gets in, I will also get in (the new house).

Comment: @fweth I'm still not sure that I understand your scenario here. As for the problem with density $1/(t+1)^2$, you certainly need regularity conditions to guarentee an optimal solution exists (e.g., finite first moment).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56756/discussion-between-fweth-and-david).